# Get Access Token from Refresh Token using cURL Google API

Tags: curl, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

How to get a new Access Token from a Refresh Token using cURL?

In PHP, I would do something like this:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
$client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
```

How to accomplish the same thing using cURL?

I was unable to find it from their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: How did you solved this?, is it possible if we could have a chat.. currently this is one of our problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the code I use:

```
# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

[Link to gist](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)

---

### The full flow with cURL

```
# Client id from Google Developer console
# Client Secret from Google Developer console
# Scope this is a space seprated list of the scopes of access you are requesting.

# Authorization link.  Place this in a browser and copy the code that is returned after you accept the scopes.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[Application Client Id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=[Scopes]&response_type=code

# Exchange Authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

Comment: @DalmTo this looks exactly what I'm looking for but for some reason, it's always giving this error `"error": "invalid_grant"`. Tried with several refresh tokens that work in PHP.

Comment: The refresh token you are sending isnt valid.  Try requesting a new one from the user and trying again.  I posted the full gits file so you can see how i exchange the authorization code for the access token and refresh token.

Comment: I am getting unsupported_grant_type error for grant_type=refresh_token..