# Where Can I Find the Google API Authentication URLs and Curl documentation?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I am having trouble identifying the documentation for authenticating the Google Drive API. I have the Client ID and Client Secret already, but don't know the current Curl format for getting the Code and Access Token. Anyone have a documentation link for where to get Google API Authentication URLs?

Comment: For example, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66069065

Comment: try searching around developers.google.com: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-auth

Comment: here's a video if you are interested https://youtu.be/hBC_tVJIx5w

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I found the Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_3