# Nodejs Sign In with Google

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0

I am a backend developer trying to create an api that has a register, login (with email and password) and sign in with google. I have the following problems:

- What will be the redirect uri as it is a pure api and I don't know which developer will integrate it
- I keep getting

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "invalid_grant: Bad Request"
}
```

even after the code worked quite well the first time

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const User = require("../models/User");

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENTID,
      clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        // Check if user already exists
        let user = await User.findOne({ "google.id": profile.id });
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user); // Log them in
        } else {
          // Create new user
          user = new User({
            fullName: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            isVerified: true,
            verified: Date.now(),
            google: {
              id: profile.id,
              token: accessToken,
            },
          });

          await user.save();
          return done(null, user);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
      }
    }
  )
);

// Passport session setup
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});

module.exports = passport;
```

This is my passport configuration

```
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);
router.use(
  "/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/api/v1/auth/login" }),
  google
);
```

This is my route

Comment: You can check out these: [i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66069065/how-to-get-new-refresh-google-oauth-token) and [ii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724003/using-refresh-token-exception-error-invalid-grant)